# Getting vector from matrix by overloading subscript operator()

Tags: c++, vector, matrix, operator-overloading

I want to do something like this:

```
Matrix m;    // (4x4 matrix)
Vector4 v;   // (4-elements vector)

m(0) = v;    // replace first 4-elements matrix row by vector v
v = m(0);    // replace vector v by first 4-elements matrix row
```

heres my code:

```
Vector4& Matrix::operator() (unsigned row)
{
    return Vector4(mat[row][0], mat[row][1], mat[row][2], mat[row][3]);
}

Vector4 Matrix::operator() (unsigned row) const
{
    return Vector4(mat[row][0], mat[row][1], mat[row][2], mat[row][3]);
}
```

the second operator works fine, but when I try to compile first one, I get this error:

**error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘Vector4&’ from an rvalue of type ‘Vector4’**

So where is the problem? It's good idea to overload operator() instead of operator[] in this case?

By getting only one element from matrix I use the other two operators:

```
float& Matrix::operator() (unsigned row, unsigned col)
{
    return mat[row][col];
}

float Matrix::operator() (unsigned row, unsigned col) const
{
    return mat[row][col];
}
```

### **Edit 1 (almost solution)**

I think I found some solution. The first operator has been replaced to:

```
Matrix::MatrixHelper operator() (unsigned row)
{
    MatrixHelper m;
    m.f1 = &mat[row][0];
    m.f2 = &mat[row][1];
    m.f3 = &mat[row][2];
    m.f4 = &mat[row][3];

    return m;
}
```

heres the definition of MatrixHelper class:

```
class MatrixHelper
{
    public:

    friend class Matrix;

    void operator= (const Vector4& v)
    {
        *f1 = v.x;
        *f2 = v.y;
        *f3 = v.z;
        *f4 = v.w;
    }

    private:

    float* f1;
    float* f2;
    float* f3;
    float* f4;
};
```

now is possible to do something like that:

```
m(0) = Vector4(3,3,3,3);
```

but then occurs new problem, when calling this:

```
(m)(0) * someScalar;
```

the second operator is never called, so I have to implement them in my MatrixHelper class right? I'm on the right track?

### **Edit 2**

OK this problem would be solved if the two operators would be working at the same time. But now only one of them can be enabled. I can not understand why always is working the first operator, for example having this code (just **example**):

```
Vector4& Matrix::operator() (unsigned row)
{
    std::cout << "Operator one is working now\n";
}

Vector4 Matrix::operator() (unsigned row) const
{
    std::cout << "Operator two is working now\n";
}
```

No matter if I am doing

> m(0) = Vector(4,4,4,4)

or

> Vector4 v = m(0)

always is working the first operator. Why?

### **Edit 3 (Solution)**

I have found some other solution. Now all it's working, but performance may be a little problem. Solution not resolved in the way I wanted and it is a little far-fetched. Here's the code:

Operators:

```
Vector4 Matrix::operator() (unsigned row)
{
    return Vector4 (&mat[row][0], &mat[row][1], &mat[row][2], &mat[row][3]);
}

Vector4 Matrix::operator() (unsigned row) const
{
    return Vector4 (mat[row][0], mat[row][1], mat[row][2], mat[row][3]);
}
```

as you can see the first operator returns a vector that takes pointers. The hard work happens now in Vector4 class instead of Matrix. Vector4 has now an extra constructor:

```
Vector4(float* x, float* y, float* z, float* w)
{
    this->px = x; this->py = y; this->pz = z; this->pw = w;
    this->x = *x; this->y = *y; this->z = *z; this->w = *w;
    pointer = true;
}
```

first line are pointers, second - variables, and third line is a boolean type variable witch means what constructor has been called (normal or pointers).

Now comes the last operator (operator=):

```
Vector4 operator= ( const Vector4& v)
{
    if ( pointer )
    {
        *px = x = v.x;
        *py = y = v.y;
        *pz = z = v.z;
        *pw = w = v.w;
    }
    else
    {
        x = v.x;
        y = v.y;
        z = v.z;
        w = v.w;
    }
}
```

If `pointer` is true that means - `px`, `py`, `pz` and `pw` are pointers to some row elements in matrix, and we have to change them. Else - just normal vector.

So now question... it is bad bad solution, or just bad? :D

Comment: Why not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375591/vector-of-vectors-to-create-matrix ?

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I have already implemented the whole matrix class, so I think don't need vectors from STL

Comment: Then you can make your Matrix to be Vector4 of Vector4's. Then this problem will be solved automatically.

Comment: Oh I see, maybe that's not a stupid idea... but it needs many alterations in my code

Comment: @Tom A vector of vectors can work but would become a problem if you need a function that returns a column or diagonal instead of a row.

Comment: @Tom The first `operator()` is called because you call it on a non-`const` object. In other words because `m` is declared non-`const`. But why don't you just use an existing linear algebra library? For example [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) which, AFAIK, has heavily optimized small vectors and matrices.

Comment: @Ali I see it now... was bad thinking the whole time. Thank you for your explanation. I know that there are some libraries, but I'd like to make my own (I'm know that's stupid :). Again thank you, now everything become clear :)

Comment: @Ali I would be grateful if you say something about my solution :)

Comment: @Tom Please consider posting your code to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . If I were you, I would either do the deep copy of the row and live with the consequences (simple code, slower program) or would use and existing linear algebra library if performance is important.

Answer (score 2):

The `Vector4` you are instantiating in the errored code is an r-value which is temporary. Aside from the fact that you can't assign it to a non-const reference, it will be destroyed when your function exits and the return value would be an invalid stack location.

One solution would be to return a different object by value that stores references to the individual elements you need and allows you to act upon them in a transparent way.

Comment: Thank you, actually I don't really understand you, but I will be trying to code that

Comment: @Tom This might help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science)
If you have any specific questions I could try to answer them.

Comment: I'm still having problems to implement that. How to make a reference to an object if object is unknown at the time when reference needs to be initialized?

Comment: @Tom You're right, it is much simpler storing pointers. Here's an example of what I was thinking: http://pastebin.com/YXmqd8HR

Comment: I think your solution is better, but now I have mind blown :)