# Initialize Vector Of Vectors in C++

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array, stl

I am trying to use vector of vectors in C++ as a 2D array. I have to read input into it from the user. The number of rows and columns are also to be input by the user.

Supose I read m * n matrix,

I tried to allocate space using reserve(m*n) but is also giving error in building.

This is a general problem I face, I mean even in strings wherein you read char by char, how do you provide it space so you can access index i (I know it can be done using .resize(given_size)) but in situations where it is not known how many chars a user will input, this can't be done (this can be circumvented using + operator but still it is not a direct solution).

So, My primary question is how  initialize the vector of vectors (not putting in values but just allocating required space, rows and columns) so that I can access [i][j] to read an value to it ?

**I know that matrix can be built using vector of vectors like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375591/vector-of-vectors-to-create-matrix) but I want to first declare a vector of vectors and then take input of rows and columns to allocate space so that I can access [i][j] to input elements.**

Comment: Just do a `vec.resize(m)` on the outer vector and a `for(int i=0; i<m; ++i) vec[i].resize(n);` to resize the inner vectors. I don't get what's your problem with `resize` and strings, but it's probably better left for another question.

Comment: You can't access `[i][j]` unless there is already a value there. So your requirements are somewhat contradictory. But I think the duplicate answers your question.

Comment: @juanchopanza No, no plz remove the duplicate tag. The vector there has been defined using the row parameter. I don't want to do that.

Comment: @adrian008 I'll remove the duplicate if you fix your question such that it is clear what exactly you are asking.

Comment: @juanchopanza okay I will frame it better.

Comment: @juanchopanza no duplicate.

Comment: @juanchopanza You had said in one of your earlier posts that you wont use vector of vectors to implement a matrix. What will you use ?

Comment: @adrian008 I would write a class that uses a single memory block (with a single vector or an array depending on requirements) and provide element access with two indices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::vector<std::vector<T>> my_vec(m, std::vector<T>(n))`

Be careful that `T`s default constructor is called for each of `m * n` members of the matrix.