# quick way of resizing vector of vectors to correct size (c++)

Tags: c++, optimization, vector

I'd like to resize a std::vector< std::vector< T > > to a known size (m, n) as efficiently as possible, ideally without any memory copying (T is float or double).

```
class Foo {
    std::vector< std::vector< T > > data;
    std::vector< std::vector< T > > data_norm;

    std::vector< T > min_values;
    std::vector< T > max_values;

    void normalize();
}
```

*data* is filled dynamically, pushing_back new data one 'row' at a time. Each 'row' is guaranteed to have the same number of elements. So it is effectively an m x n table.

Then at one point I call the *normalize*() method which:

- scans through *data*
- finds the min/max value for each *column* and writes them to *min_values*, *max_values*
- normalizes each element to the min/max of that column and stores in *data_norm*

Currently I'm doing *data_norm = data* at the start of my *normalize*() method just to make sure *data_norm* is allocated to the right size and there are no further re-allocations. But that involves copying all of the memory. Is there a way to do it without this memory copy?

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31200535/initialize-vector-of-vectors-in-c) post which suggests

```
std::vector<std::vector<T>> my_vec(m, std::vector<T>(n))
```

However in my situation *my_vec* already exists. I could create and assign a *new_vec*:

```
std::vector<std::vector<T>> new_vec(m, std::vector<T>(n));
data_norm = new_vec;
```

But I guess that's still going to have the memory copy, in fact it'll be slower than *data_norm = data* because a whole new vector (*new_vec*) is initialized and allocated, and I already have a source vector of the right size.

I was hoping there is a way of doing it with a resize-like method? But without iterating through and doing resize on each sub-vector - which would create crazy reallocations I guess.

Comment: Your question is to intialize, but at the end of you post, you say my_vec already exists, so it's not really an initialization of vector, but resizing a vector.

Comment: If efficiency is of primary concern, I would avoid `std::vector`, allocate memory for a 1-d array of size `m x n`, and provide convenience functions to access the data.

Comment: @RSahu Boost has a class to make that simple: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use `vector::resize()`, it does it without creating a temporary vector

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/

```
// resizing vector
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
  std::vector<int> myvector;

  // set some initial content:
  for (int i=1;i<10;i++) myvector.push_back(i);

  myvector.resize(5);
  myvector.resize(8,100);
  myvector.resize(12);

  std::cout << "myvector contains:";
  for (int i=0;i<myvector.size();i++)
    std::cout << ' ' << myvector[i];
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
myvector contains: 1 2 3 4 5 100 100 100 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: oh wow thanks. I didn't realize the second parameter would apply like that.

Answer (score 1):

> Currently I'm doing data_norm = data at the start of my normalize() method just to make sure data_norm is allocated to the right size and there are no further re-allocations.

First, you should simply design your program such that nobody can resize the vectors and ensure that you're not resizing them and then you can avoid this work entirely. You could put some asserts in your code to make sure the size never changes in debug mode if you want to be extra safe.

Also, if you want to do the work 'as efficiently as possible', then you should avoid using a vector of vectors, since for a rectangular matrix that's more allocations than necessary.

There's currently no standard container that provides an efficient multi-dimensional array with runtime bounds, but you can pretty easily define one. Here's a pretty minimal example.

```
template<typename T>
class vector2d {
  std::vector<T> data;
  int columns;

public:
  struct index { int r, c; };

  vector2d(index i) : data(i.r * i.c), columns(i.c) {}
  T &operator[] (index i) { return data[i.r*columns + i.c]; }
}
```

And then you can write:

```
class Foo {
    vector2d<T> data;
    vector2d<T> data_norm;

    std::vector<T> min_values;
    std::vector<T> max_values;

    void normalize();

    Foo(int n, int m) : data({n, m}), data_norm({n, m}) {}
}
```

And if you want to do the same thing for an arbitrary number of dimensions [that can be done](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/nCtKDZuwlxSdLso2) as well.

Comment: thanks for this. My data is dynamic though, so I can't design the program to not allow the vectors to be resized. A 2d->1d wrapper is a good idea though.

Comment: @memo Well whatever your requirements for resizing the matrix you should be able to ensure that it's always the right size by design, rather than rely on resizing it on demand whenever you happen to notice it's not the right size.