# #define function with variable name

Tags: c++, preprocessor-directive

I am continually writing something akin to

```
std::vector< std::vector< double > > A(N, std::vector< double >(M));
```

and I would like to replace this with something like

```
matrix A(N,M);
```

by using a `#define` directive. I've looked at [#define directives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/teas0593.aspx) and think I can create a function like `matrix(A,N,M)` that would declare a `vector` of `vectors` as follows:

```
#define matrix(A, N, M) std::vector< std::vector< double > > A(N, std::vector< double >(M))
```

but I would rather not declare my matrices as `matrix(A,N,M)`, but rather `matrix A(N,M)`. My question is - how do I use the `#define` directives to account for changing a variable name?

Comment: Using nested `vector`s as a matrix is a bad idea to begin with. Implement a proper matrix class or use an existing one. Either way, stop those useless macro hacks.

Comment: Also, looking at this question, you should most certainly read a good C++ book.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Thanks for your feedback. I have read many C++ books actually. I'm using a vector of vectors right now to implement the math ASAP. Once I have validated the math I will go back and restructure with a 'proper' matrix class as you suggested.

Either way, none of your comments so far answer the question.

Comment: If the comments were supposed to answer the question, I would have posted them as an answer. They are, however, just comments. And for testing some math stuff, there are enough linear algebra libraries readily available that properly implement matrix math.

Comment: @BaummitAugen matrices are just miserable corner cases of vectors of vectors for miserable people :D

Comment: @BaummitAugen Such as blas, lapack, eigen, cublas, etc. I'm well aware. For now, however, I am writing it from scratch as it is by far the fastest way for me to get preliminary results.

Comment: Are `N` and `M` constant expressions in your use case?

Comment: @rici yes, they are.

Comment: In that case, have you considered `template<size_t N, size_t M> using Matrix = std::array<std::array<double, M>, N>;`? That would let you write `Matrix<N, M> A;`, which is not quite what you asked for but it's still quite tidy. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b63279ac555a7a6

Answer (score 1):

You can use `typedef` and define type, something like that:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int N = 10;
    typedef std::vector< std::vector<double> matrix;
    matrix  A(N, std::vector< double >(N));
    return 0;

}
```

or more safety (if you don't know, that matrix will be right)

```
int main()
{
    int N = 10;

    typedef std::vector< std::array<double, 5> > matrix;
    matrix  A(N, std::array< double , 5 >());
    return 0;
}
```

my wrapper for matrix with vectors

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <exception>
#include <algorithm>

template< typename T >
class WrapperMatrix
{
public:
    WrapperMatrix(const int& weight, const int& length);
    void pushLine(const std::vector<T>&&);
    void pushColumn(const std::vector<T>&&);
    void display();
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> matrix;
};
template<typename T>
WrapperMatrix<T>::WrapperMatrix(const int& weight, const int& length) 
{
    this->matrix = std::vector<std::vector<T>>(weight, std::vector<T>(length));
}

template <typename T>
void WrapperMatrix<T>::pushLine(const std::vector<T>&& newLine)
{
    if (newLine.size() == this->matrix.at(0).size())
        matrix.emplace_back(std::move(newLine));
    else
        throw std::invalid_argument("Invalis syntax");
}
template <typename T>
void WrapperMatrix<T>::pushColumn(const std::vector<T>&& newColumn)
{
    if (newColumn.size() == this->matrix.size())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); ++i)
            matrix.at(i).emplace_back(std::move(newColumn.at(i)));
    }
    else
        throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid syntax");
}
template<typename T>
void WrapperMatrix<T>::display()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.at(0).size(); ++j)
            std::cout << matrix.at(i).at(j);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1{ 1,2,3,4,5 };
    std::vector<int> v2{ 1,2,3,4,5,6 };
    std::vector<int> v3{ 2,3,4,5,6 };

    WrapperMatrix<int> vw(5,5);
    try {
        vw.pushLine(std::move(v1));
        vw.pushColumn(std::move(v2));
        //vw.pushLine(std::move(v3));
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    vw.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, a vector of vectors does not properly implement a matrix.

Comment: Thanks. `typedef` is a much better idea and I'm surprised I didn't think of it first! Either way, it doesn't solve the issue of wanting to allocate on declaration.

Comment: @BaummitAugen question was deffrent, not about how create vector of vectors. I only show how define complexity type

Comment: @21koizyd I'm not saying you are technically incorrect, just saying this answer is not useful as it fails to address key issues in the code in the question. Thus my downvote.

Comment: @BaummitAugen why not like this I see the same solution in e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375591/vector-of-vectors-to-create-matrix

Comment: @21koizyd So other people had the same poor idea before. What's your point?

Comment: no, I ask why? So i check and display vector right.

Comment: @21koizyd The inner vectors don't even have to have all the same length. A matrix and a sequence of sequences are completely different data structures, the fact that one can access their elements with a similar syntax does not change that.

Comment: It's not about being symmetrical. `{{0,1},{2}}` would be a valid `vector<vector<int>>`, but no a valid matrix. They are just different things.

Comment: @BaummitAugen okey I understand what you mean.

Comment: @BaummitAugen now, second version is save, I'm right?

Comment: It's somewhat better, at least it guarantees some sort of matrix shape. I'll remove my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer to `typedef`

`using matrix = std::vector< std::vector<double>>;`

This form can be more readable, especially with function and array types. E.g. `using arr10 = Foo[10]` is clearer than `typedef Foo arra10[10]`. The = sign clearly separates what's being defined and how it's defined.

(Ignoring the whole "matrix is not a vector of vectors" discussion)