# referencing a global vector by a different name within a function

Tags: c++, function, pointers, vector, fstream

suppose you have three global vectors V1, V2, and V3.

suppose you have a function which performs a set of actions, such as VN[3]++, on one of the above vectors determined by an int value.

in python i would do something like:

```
global:
    v1 = [1,2,3]
    v2 = [1,2,3]
    v3 = [1,2,3]
    lists = [v1, v2, v3]

def function (determiner):
    list = lists[determiner]
    list[1] += 1...
```

I think in theory i could just have separate ifs for each possible value of determiner, but it seems like bad code to repeat a length of code multiple times. 
(1) What is the correct way to approach this problem? I assume I would use pointers, but I've just learned about them today and i've been struggling to get my code to work. Here's a sample of the code i've been trying.

```
   vector <int> counts0;
   vector <int> counts1;

   void editor(int determiner){
        if (determiner == 1) {
            vector<int> & count_l = counts1;
        }
        else if (determiner = 2) {
            vector<int> & count_l = counts2;
        }
        count_l[5]++;
    }
```

Comment: "suppose you have three global vectors V1, V2, and V3" - why would you want to have such things?

Comment: Can you reduce this question to a single question about the primary thing you are concerned about? It's confusing having to answer 4 questions in 1.

Comment: @sashang removed questions 2 & 3

Comment: I'm not sure why pointers would make this any better, your use of references here is fine. Given the code, I'm not sure if this design is ideal but suppose you did have global vectors and you needed to edit parts of them, there's nothing really wrong with what you're doing. I don't see how pointers would help. Note your `else if` have errors, it changes the value of `determiner` and also there's no actual `if`

Comment: @NeilButterworth It's a bioinformatics problem that would take a while to explain clearly. suppose you have a bag of Yen coins, GBP Pence, and USD coins, you have a list of coin names for each nationality (meaning three lists), and a list of counts for each coin name associated with each national name list. You remove a coin, if it's on a list, you update the associated count list; if it isn't you add it to the appropriate name list, and add a position with a value of 1 to the associated count list. This is an analogy, in reality each national list has thousands of lines.

Comment: None of that explains why they should be global.

Comment: Would it make sense to create a matrix or list / vector of vectors?  vector < vector <foo> > is valid C++.  Either that, or a vector of structs?  ex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375591/vector-of-vectors-to-create-matrix

Comment: @Tas yeah sorry i deleted the first "if" because i got frustrated not being able to indent in the text box, ill fix that. also !!!! thank you for pointing out my error! with '=' I already made that mistake earlier today! thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @NeilButterworth I made them global because they have to be called by multiple functions, knowing that, can you recommend a better approach?

Comment: Pass them by reference to the functions that need to use them.

Comment: @Kama slightly off-topic, you can avoid those errors by raising your warning level, having warnings as errors, or using `const` where applicable. Here, since `determiner` doesn't change it should be marked `const` then the compiler would error about your use.

Comment: @NeilButterworth to be fair this thread is asking how to pass by reference, if i'm understanding correctly.

Comment: @tas actually determiner is determined by a different function " check()", which, according to the above example, reads the name list for the name of a coin you took out, and returns its "index", (so if you pull out a nickle, the function finds that "nickle" is at index 3 in "dollars.txt" and returns 3 to determiner, so that the nickle count in the dollar vector is is ++'ed.

Comment: @DaveS I can see where you're coming from, the reason i didn't take that approach is because i don't know how to move to the vector and then one of the vector's positions, e.g. vectors[2][1]++

Comment: @tas sorry i meant to update but i timed out, i can read up on const, but I was trying to say that determiner changes after a couple times editor() is called: at my current configuration, every 1120 calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this, depending on what you expect. If `lists` should reference the vectors, use pointers (as you said, just remember to dereference before indexing)

```
std::vector<int> a, b, c;
std::vector<std::vector<int>*> lists = {&a, &b, &c};

void editor(int determiner)
{
    (*lists[determiner])[5]++;
}
```

If you want a copy of all vectors in `list`, don't use pointers (this can be expensive when you modify `lists` a lot, only use this approach with const data).

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> lists = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}};

void editor(int determiner)
{
    lists[determiner][5]++;
}
```