# C++ Initializing a 2d vector by 1d vector's function

Tags: c++, vector

This is what I have:

```cpp
vector<int> A {5,4,3,1};
vector<int> B {3,1};
```

I want make 2d vector C to 5*5 2d vector filled in 0.0
so I tried this:

```cpp
vector<vector<double>> C((A.size() + 1), vector<double>((B.begin() + 2),0.0));
```

But this is an error I'm getting.

```
There is no instance of a constructor with a matching C++ argument list.
            (std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::conditional_t<true, std::_Simple_types<int>, std::_Vec_iter_types<int, size_t, ptrdiff_t, int *, const int *, int &, const int &>>>>, double)
```

I can't understand the content of the error.
May I ask what is wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: What is exactly the content of the vector `C` that you want to obtain?

Comment: If you want a 5x5 2d vector of `double`s (you seem to want to initialize with `0.0`): `vector<vector<double>> C(5, vector<double>(5, 0.0));` (where the `0.0` is the same as the default you'd get if you left that argument out)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vector of Vectors to create matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375591/vector-of-vectors-to-create-matrix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cpp
vector<vector<double>> C((A.size() + 1), vector<double>((B.begin() + 2),0.0));
```

Here you are invoking this constructor of std::vector (number 3 on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)):

```cpp
constexpr vector( size_type count,
                  const T& value,
                  const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

You can see that it takes in size and value. In your nested vector instead of passing size you are passing iterator the the beginning and increment it by two. I think what you've wanted is `B.size()` instead of `B.begin()`. Also if it has to be 5 x 5 you can simply do this:

```cpp
std::vector<std::vector<double>> C(5, std::vector<double>(5, 0.0));
```

Comment: Thanks for the kind explanation! so, I change vector<vector<double>> C((A.size() + 1), vector<double>((B.begin() + 2),0.0));   to   C((A.size() + 1), vector<double>((B.front() + 2),0.0));  that is work. I will study about iterator more...